# How to log out?

Tags: discussion

How does one log out of Superuser - Stackexchange?

I created a user id and password, and was able to post as a result, 
so I'm pretty sure I'm logged in.

But I cannot find a "log out" button or link.

How does one log out??

Thanks!

Comment: why on earth would you ever log out of this website? that's madness

Answer (score 3):

You can find logout link here:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: log out]

There is a logout button on the top right of the navigation menu.